# Getting ORA-00001(unique constraint violated) when COMMITing?

Tags: oracle10g, primary-key, unique-constraint, ora-00001

We're getting a ORA-00001 (unique constraint violated) in a batch job. However, the error occurs when a COMMIT is issued, not at the time the offending record is inserted.

Questions:

- How come that the unique constraint is checked at COMMIT? (Are there some settings we can use so that the check occurs at the time of the INSERT?)
- How can we find out the offending SQL/record that lead to the unique constraint violation?

Any help is appreciated!

---

*Additional Information/Question:*

The "offending" constraint is marked as IMMEDIATE and NON-DEFERRABLE. Can this be overridden in the transaction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constraints can be marked/defined as deferrable. In that case constraint checks can be either "immediate" or "deferred". When defining the constraint you can set a default/initial value, `initially immediate` or `initially deferred`. When set to `deferred` the constraint is enforced not until you commit the transaction.
You can change the behaviour of deferrable constraints e.g. via

```
set constraints all immediate;
```

see also: http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/03-nov/o63asktom.html

Answer (score 3):

Constrains can be defined as deferred, meaning that they are checked at commit, not at the time of the data change. See the following 2 links:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/ConstraintCheckingUpdates.php

http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/03-nov/o63asktom.html

hope it helps